# Excel VBA lastrow & currentrow, add data to row if data is found or add new row

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Form that I use, It holds 3 Worksheets - Form, Data and Entries. Basically When you call a new Form with the Button it looks for the lastrow in the Entries sheet (Range "A") adds 1 and that's your new Form ID. Having multiple users use this form I have it set that It also adds the number in the Entries sheet before the form is filled, in order to reserve it so a next user cannot get duplicates.

Here's where I get caught up. I'd like to have currentrow find that sheet id and paste the data in that row, but the code I have is just adding a new row.

This is what it looks like.

```
Sub Submit()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim multiplerange As Range
Dim currentrow As Long
Dim sheetid As String
Set rng1 = Range("M1,M2,B2,F6,B7,B8,B9,B11,D11,B13,D13,I6,M6,I7,I8,I9,I11,K11,I13,K13,B15,B18,B22,E22,B23,B24,B26,E26,I22,J22,M22,K24,M24,I24,I26,K26,M26,B29,E29,B30,B31,B33,E33,I29,J29,M29,K31,M31,I31,I33,K33,M33,B36,E36,B37,B38,B40,E40,I36,J36,M36,K38,M38,I38,I40,K40,M40")
Set rng2 = Range("G2")
Set multiplerange = Union(rng1, rng2)
Dim WSEntries As Worksheet
Dim WSForm As Worksheet
Set WSEntries = Sheets("Entries")
Set WSForm = Sheets("Form")
sheetid = WSForm.Range("M1").Text
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = WSEntries.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For currentrow = 3 To lastrow
If Cells(currentrow, 1) = sheetid Then

Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For Each c In multiplerange
    WSEntries.Cells(currentrow + 1, i) = c
    i = i + 1
Next

Else
i = 1
For Each c In multiplerange
    WSEntries.Cells(lastrow + 1, i) = c
    i = i + 1
Next

End If
Next


End Sub
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Edit: I also didn't add all my declared items but this is the other part of the script. I've got everything else working just the paste part that I'm having issue with

Comment: I don't see `multiplerange` set in the code.... also `lastrow` should be long

Comment: My Bad, was just adding the part I was having an issue with - I've edited the code in full now. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!! switched to a Range method

```
lastrow = WSEntries.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For currentrow = 3 To lastrow
If WSEntries.Range("A" & currentrow) = sheetid Then

Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For Each c In multiplerange
    WSEntries.Cells(currentrow, i) = c
    i = i + 1
```